# What act as model in Angular 2

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I want to wrap my head around Angular 2 with respect to MVC framework. In Angular 1.x it was pretty straight forward to see things in MVC perspective. As far as I understand the components acts as controller and template as view in angular 2, but where does the model fit into this?

Comment: I have a question for you. where does the model fit into Angular1.x? Can you tell me? And if you know it, hopefully it means you also know how to do it in Angular2.

Comment: The scope was acting as model in angular 1.x but in Angular 2 the component class will behave as model as well as controller. I am not very sure on this. Its just that its more easy to relate in angular 1.

Comment: What about creating a model-class and using this model in component and view? :) It's nothing Angular specific..

Comment: Ya it can be done. MVC is a design pattern and we can implement it any language. Angular 1.x is stated as MVC framework and we can clearly see it, on the other hand Angular 2 looks more like component driven.

Comment: The component can act as the model, but it's better to use a service class or an object referenced by the component or service.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: @mxii Thanks for suggestion